# Probability density function of $X = \frac{P}{\cos(\theta)} - y\tan(\theta)$.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, change-of-variable

Assume that we have two independent random variables:

- $P$ is distributed on $(0,1)$ with $f_{P}(p) = 2p$.
- $\theta$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,2\pi)$.

We then define $X,Y$ such that
\begin{align*}
P = X\cos(\theta) + Y\sin(\theta).
\end{align*}

Now I want to find the distribution of the variable $X$ while given the value of $Y$.

In fact, given the value of $Y$, we have
\begin{align*}
X = \frac{P}{\cos(\theta)} - y\tan(\theta).
\end{align*}

The cumulative distribution function of $X$ is

\begin{align*}
\Pr\{X<x\} & = \Pr\Bigl\{\frac{P}{\cos(\theta)} - y\tan(\theta) < x\Bigr\} = \Pr\{P < x\cos(\theta) + y\sin(\theta) \} \\
& = \int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{x\cos(\theta) + y\sin(\theta)}_{0} \left(2p\right)\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)dPd\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \left(x\cos(\theta) + y\sin(\theta)\right)^{2} d\theta\\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \left(x^{2}\frac{1 + \cos(2\theta)}{2} + xy\sin(2\theta) + y^2\frac{1 - \cos(2\theta)}{2} \right) d\theta \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left( \pi \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right) \right) =  \frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{2}
\end{align*}

Then the pdf of $X$ can be calculated as

\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) = F'(x) = \left( \frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{2} \right)'= x.
\end{align*}

However, I felt that this result is wrong  but could not figure out which is the problem.

Could you please check my derivations and point out what is the problem for me, or give me any hints to solve it? I am very appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "We then define another two independent random variables $X,Y$ such that $P = X\cos(\theta) + Y\sin(\theta)$"? That's just one equation, you can't use it to define two variables. One might have expected something like $X=P\cos\theta$ and $Y=P\sin\theta$ – is that perhaps what you meant?

Comment: @joriki:  Yes, what you said is right as $X=P\cosθ$ and $Y=P\sinθ$. In fact, this problem is that I want to find the distribution of the intersection point between a random line represented by $(P,\theta)$ with a fixed line parallel with x-axis. Actually, $P$ is the distance from the origin to the line and $\theta$ is the angle made by the perpendicular of the line with x-axis.  Sorry for the inconvenience.